# Visual Studio 2015. IIS Server stop button is not visible

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am new to .net Platform. I just downloaded Visual Studio 2015

I created my first .net core web application

Whenever I press F5 to start the IIS server, It shows stop button

Whenever I press Ctrl + F5 to start the IIS Server, It doesn't show the stop button

I have no idea how to stop it. is there any shortcut. I even tried shift + f5

Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

You can only stop it when you start debugging (aka F5). Control+F5 is start without debugging.

You cannot stop IIS in both cases. You just close the browser, which without the stop button you can manually.

Comment: Thanks. that means I have to stop close the browser to stop the server right?

Comment: @SMANSARI IIS is a Windows service, so it never stops (unless you shut down the service explicitly).

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to Lex Li's answer, you can stop running site in IIS express like this-

Go to notification are on taskbar > right click on IIS express icon > go to your running site (under View Sites option) > choose 'Stop Site'

Refer below image-

[image: stop site]